# Jive - where to update URL for login page

Tags: jive

In this code snippet for our Jive (Hosted 8) mixed mode registration/login page (https://communities.healthstream.com/login.jspa and its template file is  /template/global/include/login-macros.ftl), do you know where to update the URL referred to here:  id="sso-login-submit<#if previewMode>-disabled". Thank you for any guidance!

```
<div id="split-auth-login-block" <#if !previewMode>style="display:none"   </#if> class="j-box j-enhanced jive-box jive-box-form jive-standard-formblock-container jive-login-reg-formblock clearfix">
    <div class="jive-box-body jive-standard-formblock clearfix">
        <div id="jive-split-auth-employeeblock" class="jive-split-auth">
            <a href="#" id="sso-login-submit<#if previewMode>-disabled</#if>">
                <strong>NRP Instructor Login</strong>
                <p>If you are an NRP Instructor, log in here.</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question with that code block

Answer (score -1):

So, sso-login-submit is pulled from the Jive admin here:

People>Settings>Single Sign-On>SAML

Find the URL here:

```
 <md:SingleSignOnService
        Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
        Location="https://sso.healthstream.com/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: This is the URL of the IdP, which has nothing to do with Jive. If you want to change this URL, this must be changed on the IdP side and then the metadata needs to be updated on the Jive side.